# Dependent Less files and jQuery plugins for modal functionality in Bootstrap 3.1 (using Customizer)

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3.1 and would like to customise the download so that it isn't bloated with unnecessary features. I need modal functionality so my question is which Less files and jQuery plugins *must* I to add to my custom build in order for Modals to work?

Customizer:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Modals:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: modals.less and modals.js. You'll also probably need normalize.less and the type.less, but remove what you don't need. Just // comment out the imports you don't want in the bootstrap.less file

Comment: This is a fork with improvements: http://jschr.github.io/bootstrap-modal/bs3.html